# any two closed subset intersect in Zariski topology on $\mathop{\cup}\limits_{i=1}^n V(x_i)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

A topological space $X$ is called disconnected if it can be written as a disjoint union $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ of (non-empty) closed subsets of $X$ not equal to $X$. It is called connected otherwise.

Let $X = \mathop{\cup}\limits_{i=1}^n V(x_i)$ be the union of the $n$ coordinate axes in the affine space $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ ($k$ a field). My aim is to show that $X$ is connected while it is clearly reducible topological space for $n>1$.

My work:

On the contrary, assume that  it can be written as a disjoint union $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ of (non-empty) closed subsets of $X$ not equal to $X$. Then $X_i=V(\mathfrak{a}_i)$ for some ideal $\mathfrak{a}_i$ in $k[x_1, \ldots,x_n]$. Then we have:

$$rad(\mathfrak{a}_1\mathfrak{a}_2)=(x_1\cdots x_n), \qquad \mathfrak{a}_1+\mathfrak{a}_2=(1).$$
So that $(x_1\cdots x_n)^m \in \mathfrak{a}_1 \cap \mathfrak{a}_2$, for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. I am looking for some contradictions which I can not find. I appreciate any comment or help in this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: See Hartshorne Chapter II Exercise 2.19

Comment: @[user37864](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/37864/user37864): Thanks for your response. But I can not find how this exercise can help me in this matter. Could you please explain a little bit more about this problem.

Comment: It gives equivalent conditions for when is an affine scheme disconnected, so you can check that you don't have orthogonal idempotents.

Alternatively, you can argue something along the following lines: If $X = X_1 \cup X_2$, where $X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset$, then $X_1,X_2$ are both closed and open. 

For each irreducible component $Y$ of $X$, either $X_i \cap Y$ is empty, or $X_i \cap Y$ is an open (hence dense subset of $Y$, as $Y$ is irreducible), but $X_i$ is closed implies that $Y\subseteq X_i$. So the $X_i$ are unions of coordinate axes, but clearly they intersect at the origin.

Comment: In the first line of your post you left out the condition that $X_1$ and $X_2$ should be disjoint for $X$ to be disconnected.

Comment: @[user3786](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/37864/user37864): Very nice approach. Thank you so much. I really enjoyed your approach to this question.